# Flutter webview two way communication with Angular

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, flutter

I have problem with webview. I am made communication from js to flutter but.
I have this problem on IOS simulator.

What to do:
I want to click btn on flutter and handle it on js func.

My code of flutter:

```
    late WebViewController _controller;
    .....
    onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller) =>
          {_controller = controller},
    ...
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(

    child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
    onPressed: () {
      _controller.evaluateJavascript('fromFlutter("From Flutter")');
    },
  ),
```

In Js side i have simple angular app, with classic AppComponent:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 declare const window: any;
 @Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
 export class AppComponent {
 title = 'testWebViewHandlers';
  constructor() {}


  fromFlutter(newTitle: any) {
   this.title = newTitle;
  }
}
```

when i click flutter btn i have this error

[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(evaluateJavaScript_failed, Failed evaluating JavaScript, JavaScript string was: 'fromFlutter("From Flutter")'
Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=0, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=TypeError: undefined is not a function, WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=0, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred}, null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:18)

i am already use JavascriptChannel to handle click form js to flutter and its work fine.

Thx for help

**SOLUTION :**

To get context of component in window object u can add it as this.
in Angular constructor or init:

> window['AppComponent'] = this; ('AppComponent' or any other)

then u have access to evaluateJavaScript in the console.

in Flutter:

> ```
>    webView.evaluateJavascript(source: "window.AppComponent.fromFlutter('test')");
> ```

Comment: The error pretty much summarizes the problem, there is no `fromFlutter` function in the global scope, as you assume when you `evaluateJavascript` on your `WebViewController`. You should first try to call that method from the console of your browser, and if it works, then it will work with the `evaluateJavascript` as well.

Comment: ye, it's angular start up project. i can call func by BTN or something, for example by constructor of component. I have only find solutions for run pure <scripts> code like 
<script>   fromFlutter(newTitle: any) {
   this.title = newTitle;
  }
</script>
maybe i have to declare function in angular differently